# Use VPS as a proxy, VPS being tunneled to a server with dynamic IP

Tags: ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, http-proxy

I'm trying to connect to a VPS as if this one was a proxy server

**Edit**
Proxy being an HTTP proxy not a SOCKS one, so that any app needing an HTTP proxy can connect to this HTTP proxy with this type of settings :

```
login:passwd@proxy_ip:port
```

but this connexion being tunneled from the VPS to a server with a dynamic IP (a raspberry pi connected to a 4g wifi), so that the proxy request is finally made by the server on the RPi

So far, I have the SSH tunnel working between the Rpi and the VPS

I did this on the Rpi :

```
ssh -N -R 9999:localhost:22 vps_user@vps_ip
```

Then from the VPS I can connect to the Rpi doing :

```
ssh pi_user@localhost -p 9999
```

So that I get connected to the RPi

**What I'm missing is the other part :**

**Edit 2 :**

I'd like to use my browser **or any app needing HTTP proxy settings** to get pages from the internet, connecting to my VPS as this one was an HTTP-proxy, the VPS tunneling the request to the RPi so that finally the Rpi will ask for the webpage...

Hope my explainations are understandable, let me know

Many thanks by advance,

Regards

Comment: I removed my answer, I didn't understand the http proxy was mandatory. Your question doesn't any http proxy installed. Maybe you should add what you did about it?

Comment: Actually I didn't install any HTTP proxy yet as I don't know how to make it work with the VPS and the SSH tunnel all together

Comment: I'm not sure about what proxy to install and how to manage the connexion to it. If once installed on the VPS, I have to forward request on the VPS to one port to another that will be forwarded through the SSH tunnel or if there is an other solution. Maybe use proxychain to send the request received on  an HTTP-proxy installed on the VPS through the SSH tunnel or an other solution... ?